# Scale weighted variable

Tags: linear-transformations

I would like to scale a vector $x$ such that after weighting, it has the following properties:

$\sum_{i} w_{i} x_{i} = 0$ and

$\sum_{i} w_{i} x_{i}^2 = 1$

where $w_{i}$ are weights that add up to one. And $x_{i}$ could be any positive value. Let‘s say

$x=\pmatrix{0.6\\1.8\\2.4\\0.2\\3.1}$  and

$w=\pmatrix{0.2\\0.15\\0.3\\0.1\\0.25}$.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Can be the weights negative?

Comment: No, they are always positive. In my case they are weights for stocks in a portfolio.

Comment: Well, the sum of positive values can never result into zero.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. Consider the following example
$$\vec{x} = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 \\1 \end{matrix} \right) $$

Then you would have
$$\sum_{i} w_ix_i = w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 = w_1+w_2 \overset{!}{=} 0$$

for the first constraint and

$$\sum_i w_ix_{i}^2 = w_1x_{1}^2 + w_2x_{2}^2 = w_1 + w_2 \overset{!}{=} 1$$
For the second constraint.
Since both equations contradict each other, you can not find a suitable solution for $\vec{w}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. What I'm trying to replicate is the following paper: https://poseidon01.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=522065105106080098103007125099071096057025068011086037123100090023122113112127002028119028004057029100116102027064070119113000111035004047048068085065120018105098112059047066099099089124001022105105017093029107082122122067087031124108027100117101002115&EXT=pdf. They exactly require those conditions. Isn't there a way to transform $x$ such that those conditions are fulfilled?

Comment: I belive that you need to make your original data zero-mean. For the above scenario, it could be at -0.5 and 0.5. Additionally, your second constraint which is the weighed 2nd moment(, or in this zero-mean scenario it is the variance), you get a sum of weights which does NOT add up to 0. Thus you can determine the weight vector by solving the linear system of equations you get. I'm on mobile now so I cannot explain better